# Concatenate NULL and string in Linq to entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

This query actually works but returns new objects with `ClientName` set to `null` where FirstName or Lastname is `null` (any one of the two). How can I get around that? I would like to have an empty string instead of `null` in those rows.

```
var clients =
                    from client in _repository.GetAll()
                    where (client.Firstname.StartsWith(query) || client.Lastname.StartsWith(query))
                    select new
                            {
                                ClientName = (client.Firstname + " " + client.Lastname).Trim(),
                                client.Firstname,
                                client.Lastname,
                                client.Address1,
                                client.Address2,
                                client.client_id,
                                client.PrettyId,
                                client.PostCode.postalcode,
                                client.PostCode.postname
                            };
```

Comment: That is the reason why there is no sense in setting string fields as nullable in database. Set FirstName and SecondName as NOT NULL and forget about such problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
((client.Firstname ?? "") + " " + (client.Lastname ?? "")).Trim();
```